# Excel listbox results in number to linked cell

Tags: excel, listbox

Like the title suggest, my listbox is resulting in a number in the link cell. If it helps, I just upgraded from 2007 to 2013. I don't remember what it was I did to make it work initially.

I select an item, the selection should appear in an adjacent cell. Seemed pretty simple, but I must be missing something.

I had to re-make the cell after the upgrade as it wasn't working at all. Now I have my list populated from a named range, but the linked cell is going to cause me to seek employment at McDonalds.

Comment: Can you share the code that isn't working properly? Are you saying when you select an item from the listbox, that item should be displayed in the adjacent cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listboxes only provide the index of the selection in the linked cell. You can easily extract the value selected using the index (in `B1` in my example) and the list item cells (`A1:A5`). Just place in a cell the following formula:

`=INDEX(A1:A5,B1`)

If your list is not based on a range but a static list you can just replicate the list in the formula encompassed by some curly brackets.

Comment: Ha! Simple enough. Thanks a ton nbayly!